# CSS Grid to have minimum number of columns possible with auto flow after wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive, css-grid

Is it possible to have a CSS grid with auto flow that minimises the number of columns after wrapping? How?

I have a grid with 6 items with auto-placement. Once not all 6 of them fit in one row, I'd like to have 3 columns and 2 rows, instead of 5 columns and 1 row, with only one element on the second one.

I'd like to avoid media queries, if possible.

---

A visual representation of what I'd like to do:

1) If all 6 items fit in one row, show them in one row.

```
| OOO OOO OOO OOO OOO OOO | 
| O1O O2O O3O O4O O5O O6O |
| OOO OOO OOO OOO OOO OOO |
```

2) If fewer than 6 elements fit in one row, show them in 2 rows with 3 items each.

```
| OOO OOO OOO         | 
| O1O O2O O3O         | 
| OOO OOO OOO         | 
|                     | 
| OOO OOO OOO         | 
| O4O O5O O6O         | 
| OOO OOO OOO         |
```

3) If fewer than 3 elements fit in one row, show them in 3 rows with 2 items each.

```
| OOO OOO   | 
| O1O O2O   | 
| OOO OOO   | 
|           | 
| OOO OOO   | 
| O3O O4O   | 
| OOO OOO   | 
|           | 
| OOO OOO   | 
| O5O O6O   | 
| OOO OOO   |
```

---

Here's what I got so far. Reduce width until the last column wraps, at that point I'd like to have 3 columns with three items each instead of one with 5 and another with 1.

```css
.grid {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #444;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  background: #5a5a;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think (not completely sure) you might want flexbox instead of grid for this.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow How would you do it with flexbox so it works with 6, 3 and 2  columns? With flexbox there's also the problem of keeping columns aligned and with the same width.

Comment: You have to ask *why* the columns would conform to arbitrary numbers. They have no reason to go from 6 to 3 to 2. Why would the container adjust like that? Why not 6 to 4 to 1? This is why media queries exist.

Comment: Because with 3 columns every row will be full. I posted the question to figure out if there's a way I don't know about that fills every row after wrapping. Media queries are not useful in my situation because this style would go in an area that can be resized independently of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Please note that I wrote the answer **before** the OP added their code to the question. However, I still think that `@media` queries are needed to solve this problem, independent of the method in which the `div` elements are displayed.

---

### Original Answer:

I've made a demonstration below using a `br` tag and `@media` queries.

Run the snippet and then press 'Full Page' to test it:

```css
.grid-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 2px;
}

.row3 {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1260px) {
  .row3 {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 636px) {
  .row3 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-box"></div>
<div class="grid-box"></div>
<div class="grid-box"></div>
<br class="row3">
<div class="grid-box"></div>
<div class="grid-box"></div>
<div class="grid-box"></div>
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid media queries, as I'd like to make a reusable component that might be used where with sidebars. Media queries make it complicated.